# Location coordinates giving wrong CGPoint Values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocationcoordinate2d

I want to get an current location CGPoint values.I can get current location values, from that i try to get it but its not giving correct origin points

```
-(void)addCircleToUserLocation{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, 50, 50);
    CGRect rect = [mapView  convertRegion:region toRectToView:mapView];
//    CGRect rect;
//    CGPoint point=[mapView convertCoordinate:center toPointToView:mapView];
//    rect.origin.x=point.x;
//    rect.origin.y=point.y;
//    rect.size.width=100;
//    rect.size.height=100;
   NSLog(@"%f,%f",rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y);

}
```

**Console:
x-700.736190,y-329.035629**

Here i am showing user location by adding this line

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
        mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;
```

adding annotation on **MAP**

```
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX      0x10000000000
- (void )createAnnotations:(NSMutableArray *)arrayList
{
    PinAnnotation*  pinAnnotation;
    [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;
    for (int i=0; i<=[arrayList count]; i++) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D cor;
        double latDelta = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);
        double lonDelta = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);
        cor.latitude=[latitude doubleValue]+latDelta;
        cor.longitude=[longitude doubleValue]+lonDelta;
        pinAnnotation = [[PinAnnotation alloc] init];
        pinAnnotation.tag=i;
        pinAnnotation.coordinate = cor;
        if (i==[arrayList count]-1) {
            coordinates=cor;
        }
        [mapView addAnnotation:pinAnnotation];
        ;
    }
    //[self setRoot:&coordinates];

    //[self zoomMapViewToFitAnnotations:mapView animated:YES];
}
```

I am adding pin around current location randomly. i want to get CGPoint of Current location values.

Comment: Please make sure that your Map has been loaded fully . That means if you are trying to get point in Viewdidload() than please have it in ViewwillAppear()

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);

CGPoint Centerpoint = [mapView convertCoordinate:center toPointToView: mapView];
```

Comment: that is also returning wrong values, x-700.736190,y-329.035629